# Android app crashing in a single phone and throwing runtime exception

Tags: java, android

I have tested my android app on 40+ phones but it is crashing on a single phone (Redmi Note 4, Android 7.0). However, the app is running successfully on another phones having Android version 7.0. I am getting this type of exceptions-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2747)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2808)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1541)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:165)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6375)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:912)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: post more stacktrace

Comment: that is the full stacktrace.